# Convert regex string to URL

Tags: regex

Im trying to convert words into URLs. the words are separated with a comma `,`. But my problem is that the first word is not taken into account, because there is no comma infort of it.

```
public static function convertHashtags($str){
        $regex = "/,+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/";
        $str = preg_replace($regex, '<a href="'.Config::get('URL').'index/hashtag/$1">$0</a>', htmlentities($str));
        return($str);
    }
```

For example `$str=june,mars,april` results that only `mars` and `april` get URLed, not `june`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your regex to:

```
$regex = '/(?<=,|^)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/';
```

to match line start or comma before your words.

You can shorten your regex to:

```
$regex = '/(?<=,|^)(\w+)/';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! but the URL looks like this now: `index/hashtag/,` its a comma instead of the word. And i made a mistake in my first post. There is no space between words. `june,mars,april`

Comment: The `m` flag is useless in this example. It is used to tell `.` to also match newlines. Since you aren't using `.`, you can remove it.